# how to fix "unorderable types: NoneType() > float()" error in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

im trying to generate a pdf of a list of employees, everything was alright until i tried to make a rowspan that groupe all the employees that are in the same department, and then i got an error, form the view i send a 3 dimensional array, employees infos inside a list of departments

i tried to get the size of the group from the view and send it in l2.6 and i tried to get it from l1|length

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black;">
            <tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;"> Service</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;"> Nom et prenom</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;width: 160px;"> Conge 1</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;width: 160px;"> Conge 2</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;width: 160px;"> Conge 3</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;width: 160px;"> Conge 4</th>
                <th style="border: 1px solid black;width: 180px;"> Total</th>
            </tr>
            {% for l1 in liste %}
            {% for l2 in l1 reversed %}
            <tr>
              {% if l2.6 != 0%}
              <td rowspan="{{l1|length}}" style="border: 1px solid black" >
                {{ l2.0 }}
              </td>
                {% endif %}

                <td style="border: 1px solid black" >
                  {{ l2.0 }}
                </td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                  {{ l2.1 }}
                </td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    {{ l2.2 }}
                </td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                  {{ l2.3 }}
                </td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                  {{ l2.4 }}
                </td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
                  {{ l2.5 }}
                </td>


              </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
```

i got this error 
TypeError at /conge_service/

unorderable types: NoneType() > float()

this is my view :

```
class conge_service(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        template = get_template('gp/pdf/conge_service.html')
        annee = datetime.now().year;
        nature = request.GET.get('n')
        if nature == '0':
            v_nature = 'de maladies'
        else:
            v_nature = 'administratifs'

        v = request.GET.get('v')
        if(v == '1'):
            v_annee = int(annee)-1
            v_tremestre = 'le quatrième'
        else:
            v_annee=annee
            # trimestre 1 annee 2019
            if(v == '2'):
                v_tremestre = 'le premier'

                # trimestre 2 annee 2019
            if(v == '3'):
                v_tremestre = 'le deuxième'

                # trimestre 3 annee 2019
            if(v == '4'):
                v_tremestre = 'le troisième'

                # trimestre 4 annee 2019
            if(v == '5'):
                v_tremestre = 'le quatrième'
        liste = []
        ss = Service.objects.all().prefetch_related()
        for s in ss:
            aa = Affectation.objects.filter(Q(date_disposition__isnull=True) & Q(Q(specialite__service_id = s.id) | Q(option__service_id = s.id))).prefetch_related()
            personnel_service = []
            x = 0
            for a in aa:
                personnel_liste = []
                cc = Cessation.objects.filter(Q(personnel_id=a.personnel_id) & Q(nature_cessation=nature))
                if v == '1' or v == '5':
                    s1 = str(v_annee)+"-09-01"
                    d = datetime.strptime(s1, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
                    cc = cc.filter(date_cessation__gt=d)
                elif v == '3':
                    s1 = str(v_annee) + "-03-01"
                    d1 = datetime.strptime(s1, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
                    s2 = str(v_annee) + "-06-01"
                    d2 = datetime.strptime(s2, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
                    cc = cc.filter(Q(date_cessation__gt=d1) and Q(date_cessation__lte=d2))
                elif v == '4':
                    s1 = str(v_annee) + "-06-01"
                    d1 = datetime.strptime(s1, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
                    s2 = str(v_annee) + "-09-01"
                    d2 = datetime.strptime(s2, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
                    cc = cc.filter(Q(date_cessation__gt=d1) and Q(date_cessation__lte=d2))
                elif v == '2':
                    s1 = str(v_annee) + "-03-01"
                    d = datetime.strptime(s1, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
                    cc = cc.filter(date_cessation__month__lte=d)
                nom_prenom = str(a.personnel.nom)+" "+str(a.personnel.prenom)
                personnel_liste.insert(0, nom_prenom)
                i = 1
                for c in cc:
                    j = 0
                    if i < 5:
                        j = j + int(c.duree)
                        personnel_liste.insert(i, j)
                    i = i + 1
                if i < 4:
                    for k in range (i,5):
                        personnel_liste.insert(k, 0)
                personnel_liste.insert(5, personnel_liste[1] + personnel_liste[2] +personnel_liste[3] +personnel_liste[4])
                personnel_liste.insert(6, 0)
                personnel_service.append(personnel_liste)
                x = x + 1
            personnel_liste = []
            personnel_liste.insert(0,s.value )
            i1=0
            i2=0
            i3=0
            i4=0
            i5=0
            for p in personnel_service:
                i1 = i1 + p[1]
                i2 = i2 + p[2]
                i3 = i3 + p[3]
                i4 = i4 + p[4]
                i5 = i5 + p[5]
            personnel_liste.insert(1,i1 )
            personnel_liste.insert(2,i2 )
            personnel_liste.insert(3,i3 )
            personnel_liste.insert(4,i4 )
            personnel_liste.insert(5,i5 )
            personnel_liste.insert(6,x )
            personnel_service.append(personnel_liste)
            liste.append(personnel_service)


        context = {
        'annee':v_annee,
        'tremestre':v_tremestre,
        'nature':v_nature,
        'liste':liste
        }
        html = template.render(context)
        pdf = render_to_pdf('gp/pdf/conge_service.html', context)
        if pdf:
            response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
            n = random.randint(100, 100000)
            filename = "statistique_%s.pdf" %n
            content = "inline; filename='%s'" %(filename)
            download = request.GET.get("download")
            if download:
                content = "attachment; filename='%s'" %(filename)
            response['Content-Disposition'] = content
            return response
        return HttpResponse("Not found")
```

and this is the erroe traceback 
 /home/kossay/PycharmProjects/gp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner

```
            response = get_response(request)

 …
```

▶ Local vars
/home/kossay/PycharmProjects/gp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response

```
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

 …
```

▶ Local vars
/home/kossay/PycharmProjects/gp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response

```
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

 …
```

▶ Local vars
/home/kossay/PycharmProjects/gp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py in view

```
            return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

 …
```

▶ Local vars
/home/kossay/PycharmProjects/gp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py in dispatch

```
        return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

 …
```

▶ Local vars
/home/kossay/PycharmProjects/gp/gp/views.py in get

```
        pdf = render_to_pdf('gp/pdf/conge_service.html', context)

 …
```

▶ Local vars
/home/kossay/PycharmProjects/gp/gp/utils.py in render_to_pdf

```
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)

 …
```

▶ Local vars
/home/kossay/PycharmProjects/gp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xhtml2pdf/document.py in pisaDocument

```
        doc.build(context.story)

 …
```

▶ Local vars
/home/kossay/PycharmProjects/gp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/reportlab/platypus/doctemplate.py in build

```
                    self.handle_flowable(flowables)

 …
```

▶ Local vars
/home/kossay/PycharmProjects/gp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/reportlab/platypus/doctemplate.py in handle_flowable

```
                                (self._fIdent(f,60,frame),_fSizeString(f),self.page, self.frame.id,

 …
```

▶ Local vars
/home/kossay/PycharmProjects/gp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/reportlab/platypus/doctemplate.py in _fIdent

```
            return f.identity(maxLen)

 …
```

▶ Local vars
/home/kossay/PycharmProjects/gp/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/reportlab/platypus/tables.py in identity

```
            tallest = '(tallest row %d)' % int(max(rh))

 …
```

▶ Local vars

Comment: can you add your view and error traceback?

Comment: i did, check the modification